# Saving textfield values in array in the same order as TableView Cell even after some cells are deleted

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a TableView that allows user to add cells for text entry.

I implemented textfield delegate method that watches the change in the cell's textfield and store the text value in array.

I currently assign `indexPath.row` of cellForRowAtIndexPath method as a tag value of cell's textfields. And I use that tag as the index of array for updating values.

But this approach causes issue once I delete some cells and add new cells to store new value. Values get stored in random index of array.

How do I save values in array in the same index order as the table cell even after some cells are deleted?

```
var stepCount = 1
var stepOrder = ["1"]
var steps = [""]

@IBAction func stepTextFieldDidChange(sender: UITextField) {
    steps[stepTextField.tag] = sender.text!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell?

    if tableView == self.stepTableView {
        let aCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StepCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StepCell
        stepTextField = aCell.getTextField()
        stepTextField.tag = indexPath.row
        aCell.stepTextField.delegate = self
        aCell.configureStepCell(stepOrder[indexPath.row], step: steps[indexPath.row])
        cell = aCell
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if tableView == stepTableView {

        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            if stepOrder.count > 1 {
                steps.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                stepTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                stepTableView.reloadData()
            }   
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func addStep(sender: AnyObject) {
    stepCount++
    stepOrder.append("\(stepCount)")
    steps.append("")
    stepTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    stepTableView.reloadData()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you leave out code from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? I do not see how it would compile. Also, are you wanting the text values to be stored even if the cell has been deleted? I am not sure that I am understanding the question.

Comment: @Caleb You're right, I left out some code from the source for brevity. I've updated that code block with original source. I do not want to store values that are deleted. When it's easier to start over than editing, user would delete a cell and add a new cell. I need to store the new value from the new cell but my current implementation doesn't store properly after cells are deleted.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the cellForRow.. or deletion logic. What does your insertion logic look like? Also, are the values in the wrong order immediately after deleting, or only after inserting new ones?

Comment: They get mixed in wrong order after `add step` is pressed. I updated the question with that function.

Comment: So deleting works fine? Where is your insert code?

Comment: Delete works fine.

Comment: Sorry I missed this before, why do you have a reference to a `UITextField`? Using `stepTextField` could cause problems. You can use `sender.tag` and `aCell.stepTextField.tag` in these places. Also, what is `stepCount` used for? You increment it in `addStep`, but you do not decrement it in `Delete`.

Comment: Using tag values is problematic as you have found due to the impact of row renumbering. I would suggest that you create a class to store your step count (it will have a single Int property) and then store instances of these classes in your array. Add a property to your custom cell so that you can store a reference to the relevant step count object in the cell,  now you can find the right object to update straight from the cell without worrying about the source array index

Comment: @Caleb I have a reference to UITextField because it's an IBOutlet of custom class and I need a reference in the ViewController class. `stepCount` is merely a label of steps (1,2,3 ... in the attached screenshot) and this doesn't get stored in array. I have a method that decrements it which I left out in the question.

Comment: @Paulw11 I think you're on point with my problem. Would you be able to show me the structure you're suggesting in an answer? It's a little hard to picture your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tags is difficult because, as you have found out, the index will change as you manipulate the table data.

Although it is a bit of overhead for a simple string, I would create a `Step` class and store an array of these.  Then you can store a reference to the `Step` instance in your custom cell and update it from your delegate method.

On the subject of the delegate, you should move the `UITextField` delegate method into your cell class and provide a new protocol to let your view controller know about the change.

```
class Step {
    var stepValue = ""

    convenience init(_ value:String) {
        self.init()
        self.stepValue=value
    }
}

protocol StepDelegate {
    func stepValueChanged(step:Step, newValue:String) -> Void
}

In your cell class you will have:

var delegate : StepDelegate?
var step: Step!

func stepTextFieldDidChange(sender: UITextField) {
    self.step.stepValue = = sender.text!
    self.delegate?.stepValueChanged(self.step,newValue:self.step.stepValue)
}
```

In your view controller you will have:

```
var steps = [Step]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell?

    if tableView == self.stepTableView {
        let aCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StepCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StepCell

        let step=self.steps[indexPath.row]

        aCell.delegate=self
        aCell.step=step

        aCell.configureStepCell(step)
        cell = aCell
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if tableView == stepTableView {

        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
                steps.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                stepTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade) 
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func addStep(sender: AnyObject) {

    let newStep=Step("\(self.steps.count+1)")
    let newPath=NSIndexPath(forRow: self.steps.count, inSection: 0)
    steps.append(newStep)
    self.stepTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    if (self.steps.count > 1) {
        return .Delete 
    } else {
        return .None     // Don't allow deletion of the last item in the table
    }
}
```

Comment: I have omitted the `stepCount` stuff for simplicity; you should be able to determine that from the index in the array anyway

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain what this is for? `self.delegate?.stepValueChanged(self.step,newValue:self.step.stepValue)` not sure how this newValue is determined also.

And why is `aCell.step=step` necessary?

Comment: That line calls the delegate method in your view controller to tell it that the value has changed.  The new value is determined the same as it is now; through something calling `stepValueDidChange`, except that method is now in your tableview cell class rather than in the view controller.  This could be called by the text field delegate method for example.  The `aCell.step=step` puts a reference to the `Step` instance into the cell class so that it can update the data model directly

Comment: In viewcontroller, what's the best way to convert values of steps (class type array) to string? My original implementation used a normal array which I could simply map to string but not sure in this case. Do for loop and concatenate values to string?

Comment: And do I need to add `StepDelegate` to ViewController class declaration like `class ViewController: .... , StepDelegate` ? I'm getting error on `aCell.delegate=self` without it. But even declared, I still get `ViewController does not conform to protocol 'StepDelegate' `

Comment: Yes, you need to add the StepDelegate to your class inheritance list.  You then need to implement the `stepValueChanged` method to comply with the protocol.  I didn't show that because I dint know what you want to do.

Comment: I see. I don't really have anything to implement in stepValueChanged method so I guess I can leave it a blank function. I've asked this and this will be my last question - what's the best way to convert containing values of var steps = [Steps]()  (class type array) to string? My original implementation used a normal array which I could simply map to string but not sure in this case. Do for loop and concatenate values to string?

Comment: You can't use an intrinsic type such as String because it will be passed by value, not reference, so an update to the value elsewhere won't change the value that is in the array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109098/discussion-between-seong-lee-and-paulw11).

Comment: I'm getting index out of range runtime error on `let step = self.steps[indexPath.row]` I think it's saying there is no instantiated object to configure cell upon.

Comment: You need to load some data into the array.  What are you returning for `numberOfRowsInSection` ?

Comment: This is for creating new recipe data so it shouldn't return anything except "" to populate a cell.  I tried with `let firstStep = Step("")` or 
        `steps[0].stepValue = ""` in the hope to instantiate first object but error remains.